# Cannot resolve keyword 'location' into field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, leaflet

I installed django and I would like to use leaflet to display the position of my weather station.

I found that [nice tutorial](https://www.paulox.net/2021/07/19/maps-with-django-part-2-geodjango-postgis-and-leaflet/) and I could complete with the exemple scripts

However, now I would like to apply that exercise to my project. I have a database with about less of one million of measures and I need to keep the structure of my database/table. I will do my best to describe my problem.

My problem start [here](https://github.com/pierrot10/Django/blob/master/EcoSensors/console/map/viewsets.py#L11) (viewsets.py) and [here](https://github.com/pierrot10/Django/blob/master/EcoSensors/console/map/serializers.py#L27) . As I understand, the 'location' match to a field of my table, which should contain a value similar to this

```
'POINT(6.000251769184164 46.19337852885697)',0
```

because the type of the field is POINT.
However, my database does not have a such field. Instead, I have a field `station_lat` (float(8.6)) and `station_lng` (float(8.6)), where I save the latitude and longitude. That the reason why, I have the error, because it can not find 'location'

> Cannot resolve keyword 'location' into field. Choices are:
> fields_id_field, fields_id_field_id, id_station, installed, map,
> sensors, station_active, station_alt, station_archive,
> station_created, station_description, station_lat, station_lng,
> station_longname, station_name, station_order,
> stations_types_id_stations_type, ttn_app_id, ttn_dev_id,
> ttn_hardware_serial

As I have to use my database as the fields are defined, and as 'geo_field is mandatory, I first would like to know, if in my [serializerer.py file](https://github.com/pierrot10/Django/blob/master/EcoSensors/console/map/serializers.py#L27), I can adapt the 'geo_field' to search for the fields 'station_lat' and 'station_lng) and convert it in the following format

```
'POINT(6.000251769184164 46.19337852885697)',0
```

I think, I am going to have a similar issue to solve in the viewsets.py field, but for now if I comment that [line](https://github.com/pierrot10/Django/blob/master/EcoSensors/console/map/viewsets.py#L11), it does not generate an error.

I hope that few words are enough to understand my worries, because I am deseperated :(

Many thanks for any tips and hints, or solution you can provide to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the **location** field in your model **Stations**, and just change it in the **save()** method to satisfy the POINT format:

```py
from django.contrib.gis.db.models import PointField
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

class Stations(models.Model):
    ...
    location = PointField(blank=True, null=True, srid=4326)
    station_lat = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    station_lng = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'stations'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.location = Point(float(self.station_lng), float(self.station_lat))
        super(Stations, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hello, so many thanks for your help. I tried something else different, but I want to try your proposition because it look very interesting. But just a question. You said, I can keep the 'location' field, in my model, but does I need to create a field 'location' in my database as well? If I have to create a filed 'location' in my DB/table, does the save() will update the field 'location'. If, it's the case, the field 'location', will it updated with the same value, each time I refresh the page? I believe, I do not need to create a field in my DB, then what does save(). I am bit confuse. Thank

Answer (score 0):

So many thank, it's really better, but somethings is going well :).

I modified my models files as you proposed.

- https://github.com/ecosensors/Django/blob/main/EcoSensors/console/map/models.py#L9 and Line 10
- https://github.com/ecosensors/Django/blob/main/EcoSensors/console/map/models.py#L275
- https://github.com/ecosensors/Django/blob/main/EcoSensors/console/map/models.py#L292

I needed to create a field 'location' into my database

Now, this https://github.com/ecosensors/Django/blob/main/EcoSensors/console/map/serializers.py#L24 do not generate an error great!

and then when I load my pages and I can see the [right structure (See image)](https://eco-sensors.ch/temp/geometry.png)

However, as you can see the geometry entry is null. Which (may be) make sens, because, in my DB, the field 'location' has no value, and have the NULL value.

> does the save() will update the field 'location'?.

I guess yes!

May I ask you to confirm that

> If I have to create a filed 'location' in my DB/table, does the save()
> will update the field 'location'. If, it's the case, the field
> 'location', will it updated with the same value, each time I refresh
> the page?

So many thank for your help, that helped me to go one step ahead. (I am a beginer)

Have a nice week-end

Answer (score 0):

It works, thanks, excepted for one things.
I had to create the field 'location'. I had a problem while creating that field and I solve it following that [article](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173543/cant-add-point-not-null-column-to-mysql-table)

I can see only one marker in my map, but in reallity, all markers are showed, but all are at the same location. That the reason why I see only one marker.

If now I look at the serializer, it returns me that

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-1",
                "station_lat": 46.187164,
                "station_lng": 5.997526
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-2",
                "station_lat": 46.173527,
                "station_lng": 6.003618
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-3",
                "station_lat": 46.186268,
                "station_lng": 5.997424
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-4",
                "station_lat": 46.173153,
                "station_lng": 6.003011
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-5",
                "station_lat": 46.187016,
                "station_lng": 5.997001
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-6",
                "station_lat": 46.173393,
                "station_lng": 6.004297
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-7",
                "station_lat": 46.186146,
                "station_lng": 5.997017
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-8",
                "station_lat": 46.172722,
                "station_lng": 6.00308
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-9",
                "station_lat": 46.184677,
                "station_lng": 5.997972
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-10",
                "station_lat": 46.182545,
                "station_lng": 5.999088
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-11",
                "station_lat": 46.185596,
                "station_lng": 5.996834
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-12",
                "station_lat": 46.182682,
                "station_lng": 6.003728
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-13",
                "station_lat": 46.184441,
                "station_lng": 5.999066
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-14",
                "station_lat": 46.172466,
                "station_lng": 6.00361
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 15,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-15",
                "station_lat": 46.17223,
                "station_lng": 6.002607
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-16",
                "station_lat": 46.183529,
                "station_lng": 6.006996
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 17,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-17",
                "station_lat": 46.172356,
                "station_lng": 6.004136
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 18,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-18",
                "station_lat": 46.179119,
                "station_lng": 6.004328
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 20,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-20",
                "station_lat": 46.182545,
                "station_lng": 5.999088
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 21,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-21",
                "station_lat": 46.185722,
                "station_lng": 5.997623
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 22,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-22",
                "station_lat": 46.17284,
                "station_lng": 6.002612
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 23,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-23",
                "station_lat": 46.184319,
                "station_lng": 5.998923
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 24,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-24",
                "station_lat": 46.184345,
                "station_lng": 5.998887
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 25,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-25",
                "station_lat": 46.183109,
                "station_lng": 6.006879
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 26,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-26",
                "station_lat": 46.183361,
                "station_lng": 6.006943
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 27,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-27",
                "station_lat": 46.217918,
                "station_lng": 6.016133
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 28,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-28",
                "station_lat": 46.217934,
                "station_lng": 6.014958
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 29,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-29",
                "station_lat": 46.217575,
                "station_lng": 6.01465
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 30,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-30",
                "station_lat": 46.217575,
                "station_lng": 6.01465
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 31,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-31",
                "station_lat": 46.184528,
                "station_lng": 5.999068
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 32,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-32",
                "station_lat": 46.183529,
                "station_lng": 6.006996
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 33,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-33",
                "station_lat": 46.183769,
                "station_lng": 6.007091
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 34,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-34",
                "station_lat": 46.183132,
                "station_lng": 6.006629
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 35,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-35",
                "station_lat": 46.183407,
                "station_lng": 6.006712
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 36,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-36",
                "station_lat": 46.183582,
                "station_lng": 6.006712
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 37,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-37",
                "station_lat": 46.183762,
                "station_lng": 6.006895
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 38,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-38",
                "station_lat": 46.183144,
                "station_lng": 6.006361
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 39,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-39",
                "station_lat": 46.183449,
                "station_lng": 6.006433
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 40,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-40",
                "station_lat": 46.183567,
                "station_lng": 6.006497
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 41,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-41",
                "station_lat": 46.183796,
                "station_lng": 6.006625
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 42,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "station_name": "st-42",
                "station_lat": 46.183132,
                "station_lng": 6.007131
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

We can see geometry, which has always the same value

```
"geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.000251769184164,
                    46.19337852885697
                ]
            },
```

It's look like the field 'location' is not updated. Why?
May be, I do not really understand [this part here](https://github.com/ecosensors/Django/blob/main/EcoSensors/console/map/models.py#L292)

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.location = Point(float(self.station_lng), float(self.station_lat))
        super(Stations, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When is performed the saved/updated? Should I run `./manager.py makemigrations` and `./manager.py migrate` to update the 'location' field?

Many thanks!!!

Comment: No, the migration will not help. As I have an admin page, I can edit my station and and I did a small modification. After saving, my location filed was update and the markers are all shown in my map. Great!

Comment: This answer looks more a question than answer. Please consider post another question if you need more information.